# Editing and Reading Files (LPTHW Exercise 16)

Tags: python

I've been working on exercise 16 in Zed Shaw's Learning Python the Hard Way book and I did a small script to try and see if I fully understand it. However, I got stuck at a small segment which I hope you guys would be able to help with... This is the exercise I was doing for reference:

```
from sys import argv

script, filename = argv

print "We're going to erase %r." % filename
print "If you don't want that, hit CTRL-C (^C)."
print "If you do want that, hit RETURN."

raw_input("?")

print "Opening the file..."
target = open(filename, 'r+')
print "Displaying the file contents:"
print target.read()

print "Truncating the file. Goodbye!"
target.truncate()

print "Now i'm going to ask you for three lines."

line1 = raw_input("line 1: ")
line2 = raw_input("line 2: ")
line3 = raw_input("line 3: ")

print "I'm going to write these to the file."

target.write(line1)
target.write("\n")
target.write(line2)
target.write("\n")
target.write(line3)
target.write("\n")

print "And finally, we close it."
target.close()
```

And this is my code,

```
from sys import argv
script, user_name, filename = argv

print "Hello %r! I'm the %r script!" % (user_name, script)
print "Well %r, today we're going to do something very special!" % user_name
print "What are we going to do? Well you'll find out! Press ENTER to 
continue after the prompts!"

raw_input(">")

print "We are going to learn how to read and overwrite files today %r!" % 
user_name
print "Now, let's open and read what's in this file %r?" % filename
target = open(filename)
print target.read()

#The output reads:
#HELLO ITS ME

raw_input(">")

print "Phew! Now that was a handful"
print "Now let's erase all of that!"
abc = open(filename, 'w')

print "Now I'm going to ask you for 2 new lines!"
line1 = raw_input("Line 1: ")
line2 = raw_input("Line 2: ")

#Line 1: HELLO ITS NOT ME THIS TIME
#Line 2: NOOOOO

abb = abc.write("%r\n%r" % (line1, line2))
print abb.read()
```

The idea behind this script is that I want to write a basic tutorial for myself to show 3 things: 
1) I want the script to read and print out a basic notepad.txt file 
2) I want the script to truncate this basic notepad file & write 2 lines of raw input into this file
3) I want the script to print out the new file

And now some questions, 
The most pressing problem I have with this script is that I can't get the last few lines to run, I get an error instead:

```
Traceback(most recent call last):
File "ex3.py", line27, in <module>
print abb.read()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'read'
```

Would anyone be able to shed some enlightenment on the matter? I'm completely new to programming so do be patient with your explanation! I'm also aware that the community feels LPTHW is not the best book to start with for python learning but I decided to give it a go as my first introduction to programming! Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why are you trying to read from the result of calling write?

Comment: `file.write(str)` returns `None` (which you could look at as nothing); the method simply writes the data to the file.  Setting `abb = abc.write(...)` results in `abb` being set to `None` (**not** the file), and `None` has no read method.

Comment: Since your are new at coding, I have to stress that debugging is a crucial skillset for any coder, and is something you need to learn early and often. If someone gives you this answer it will only be of limited value; being shown obvious mistakes are only a little instructive. But if you debug your way to a solution you get much more value from what you learn. https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: Hi scott, I'm trying to print the new result of the notepad.txt file with the new written lines

Answer (score 0):

The interpreter is telling you exactly what the problem is: File.write returns nothing, i.e. it returns None, and you can't call the read() method on a None type. Remove "abb = ", and change

```
print abb.read()
```

To

```
print abc.read()
```

It should work fine then.

Comment: I wanted to print out the results of writing the new lines into abb, not sure how to go about doing that

Comment: Exactly what do you mean by the results of writing the new lines? The method has no results. You mean write whether the operation failed or succeeded?

Comment: Hi, I may be wrong in saying this, but I wanted to rewrite the notepad.txt file with the raw_input of 2 new lines, and then print out the notepad.txt file

Comment: You mean printing the updated contents of the text file?

Comment: Yeap! Just like how I printed out the contents of the text file in line 11-14

Comment: Just close the file, reopen it, read the contents, and print them!

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are confused about what is returned when you write to a file. If you check what is returned to abb when you write to file, you will find that it is an integer representing the number of characters you wrote to the file.

```
abb = abc.write("%r\n%r" % (line1, line2))
```

After this line, an integer is stored in `abb`.

```
print abb.read()
```

When you try to run the `read` method on abb(an integer), this will predictably produce an error indicating that your integer object does not have a read method.

If you wish to view the file you have written after writing to it, you need to either originally open the file in read and write mode, or close the file for writing and read from a new file object.

```
abc.write("%r\n%r" % (line1, line2))
abc.close()
abb = open(filename, 'r')
print abb.read()
abb.close()
```